# conflict while installing mayavi into anaconda

Tags: anaconda, mayavi

Good day,
My colleague asked my to install Anaconda and mayavi and I am novice with this topic and I decided to do the tasks on a new ubuntu installation

Here are my tasks before my issue

1. I fresh installed a Ubuntu 16.04
2. I ran all update apt-get update/upgrade
3. I created an user account (anna) and add it in sudo group
4. I loged into anna account
5. I downloaded Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh for python 2.7
6. I installed with the command sudo bash Anaconda2-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
7. I installed anaconda in /opt/anaconda2 instead to the /home/anna/anaconda2 (for all user usage) and I say YES to have the line export PATH="/opt/anaconda2/bin:$PATH" in .bashrc file of anna
8. I run source /home/anna/.bashrc

After the anaconda installation, I could see a successful message regarding the installation

Now my colleague asked me to install mayavi and she provided me the following link [mayavi](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/mayavi)

Then I simply enter the following command
`conda install -c anaconda mayavi=4.5.0`

And here start my problem. I can not well understand the conflict but apparently there is a conflict and I have no idea how to solve it. Here is the command and the message

```
anna@pc17:~$ conda install -c anaconda mayavi=4.5.0
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - mayavi 4.5.0* -> pyqt 4.* -> qt >=4.8.6,<5.0
  - mayavi 4.5.0* -> pyqt 4.* -> sip >=4.16.4,<4.18
  - navigator-updater -> pyqt >=5.6 -> qt 5.6.*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I have no idea what does mean the above message and how to solve me problem.
Is there depencies that I have to additionally install?

For information the above command return me this:

```
anna@cryospc17:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)
anna@cryospc17:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

Did I correctly try t install mayavi?

Thank a lot for any help you can provide me

Answer (score 4):

To complete the install of mayavi, you have to first install the following depence

```
conda install -c anaconda vtk=6.3.0
conda install -c anaconda pyside=1.2.1
```

Then install mayavi

```
conda install -c anaconda mayavi=4.5.0
```

It may possible, you have to remove pyqt

```
conda uninstall pyqt
```

We finally could install anaconda and mayavi sucessfully.
I hope it help
Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpfull to others. It must be anaconda for python 2.7 currently and the follows worked.

Install anaconda for python 2.7, then try the follows:

```
conda uninstall pyqt
conda uninstall navigator-updater

conda install pyqt=4
conda install vtk
conda install envisage
conda install pyside
conda install apptools=4.4.0
conda install mayavi
```